# Declaring javascript variables as specific types

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-declaration

The title says it all, but I will provide more clarification:

After seeing many samples of javascript where all variables are declared as type `var`, and seeing support for other datatypes, why aren't variables of a specific datatype declared as such? Meaning, why isn't this:

`string hello = 'Hello, World'`

used instead of

`var hello = 'Hello, World'`

Looking at sites like [OReilly Javascript](http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/learning-javascript/javascript-datatypes-variables.html) shows that there are reserved words for other types. Again, why aren't they used? Wouldn't it make lines like this: `typeof(variable)==='string';` no longer needed?

Comment: Javascript is an untyped language. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964910/is-javascript-an-untyped-language

Comment: @JonasG.Drange ECMAScript is a [*dynamically* typed](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DynamicTyping) language. (Values still have types and thus can't be *un*-typed language.)

Comment: @pst read the linked answer carefully. There is a deliberate abuse of the language "untyped" to be a shorthand for "no static types." I disagree with that abuse, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Quite simply, JavaScript variables do not have types. The *values* have types.

The language permits us to write code like this:

```
var foo = 42;
foo = 'the answer';
foo = function () {};
```

So it would be pointless to specify the type in a variable declaration, because the type is dictated by the variable's value. This fairly common in "dynamic" languages.

Comment: So it's not possible to declare a type beforehand?

Comment: what if i do `var speed : float=10.00;`

Comment: @AVIKDUTTA that's syntactically invalid JavaScript.

Comment: @AVIKDUTTA That is valid UnityScript (the version of JavaScript that the game engine Unity uses), but not JavaScript.

Comment: @MattBall it appears you are saying there is no way to always expect a variable value to always be a certain type in JavaScript? is that correct?  Is this something that we "can" do with TypeScript?

Comment: @klewis Yes, There isn't no way to expect certain type in JavaScript but We could certainly do with TypeScript.