# true/false vs int in JavaScript (unexpected behavior)

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, this

I'am kind of new to javascript and today I was working on a function that basically toggles a value and displays it as alert but I stumbled across a weird behavior of JavaScript relating to true/false and 0/1.

**The following code , when user clicks on toggle anchor link, it doesn't seem to toggle the value and the alert always gives "true" (which i thought should happen):**

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="toggle"> toggle </a>'+ document.body.innerHTML;
function f() {
    this.status = true;
    var btn = document.getElementById("toggle")
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (this.status == true) {
             alert(this.status)
            this.status = false;
        } else {
            alert(this.status)
            this.status = true;
        }

     }, false)
}

f()
```

**But if I use 0 and 1 instead of true/false the code works for some reason.**

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="toggle"> toggle </a>' +document.body.innerHTML;

function f() {
    this.status = 1;
    var btn = document.getElementById("toggle")
    btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    if(this.status==1){
         alert(this.status)
         this.status = 0;
    }else{
        alert(this.status)
        this.status = 1;
      }

     },false)
 }

 f()
```

I have no idea what's going on here, Is this because of `this` pointer i am using in the function or something?.

Comment: why don't you use === instead of == ?

Comment: JavaScript has a more complex notion of equality than you might be familiar with in other languages, but it is fortunately a very well-understood notion; check out [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) for an introduction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your function `f` is called without `new` so the `this` refers to the [`window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), which already has a[`status` property with its own meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status).

You can see this if you print its type:

```js
function f() {
    this.status = true;
    console.log(typeof this.status);
 }

 f()
```

Note how the result is `string` instead of the expected `boolean`.

But if you name it differently:

```js
function f() {
    this.myprop = true;
    console.log(typeof this.myprop);
 }

 f()
```

It yields the correct type.

So to make it work you need only to change its name. But the `if` `else` logic you have to invert the `boolean` can be turned into a `!`(not), which simplifies the code a lot:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="toggle"> toggle </a>' + document.body.innerHTML;

function f() {
  this.myStatus = true;
  var btn = document.getElementById("toggle");
  
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    this.myStatus = !this.myStatus; //here the value is inverted only with the ! (not)
    console.log(this.myStatus);
  }, false);
}

f();
```

But using the `window` object is discouraged, for reasons much like the one you were experiencing, and the `myStatus` property is still being stored there.

You can improve the solution a bit more:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="toggle"> toggle </a>' + document.body.innerHTML;

function f() {
  let myStatus = true;
  var btn = document.getElementById("toggle");
  
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    myStatus = !myStatus; //here the value is inverted only with the ! (not)
    console.log(myStatus);
  }, false);
}

f();
```

Also, don't forget to finish the statements with the semicolons, i noticed that you had almost none of them.

Comment: Worth noting that you're still adding myStatus to the window object, which isn't necessarily a great idea unless you're doing it on purpose and can articulate why you want it there.

Comment: on the side note what is the difference between `let` and `var` . In the last snippet why did you used `let` for myStatus and `var` for btn ?

Comment: @rov.er `let` guarantees you scope, while `var` doesn't. Also it works better in closures and other minor details. Check the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to JavaScript you probably haven't heard, but you should [know when to use === instead of ==](http://2ality.com/2011/12/strict-equality-exemptions.html) (hint: always).

In a nutshell, because [JavaScript is weakly/un-typed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/964983/1763258) it can be difficult to know if you're actually comparing two of the same thing (numbers) or two different things (number and object):

```
new Number(10) == 10 // true
new Number(10) === 10 // false
```

Because:

```
typeof Number(10) // returns number
typeof 10 // returns number
typeof new Number(10) // returns object
```

^ Above example from https://coderwall.com/p/bqurhg/why-always-use-in-javascript

Comment: @DragonKnight  can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Other people have posted some good responses, but here's my two cents.

You can initialize a local variable in your function that will initialize a value and then alternate on that value when the button is clicked. Your use of `this` notation does not seem to be necessary here.

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="toggle"> toggle </a>'+ document.body.innerHTML;
function f() {
    var status = true;
    var btn = document.getElementById("toggle")
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (status === true) {
            alert(status)
            status = false;
        } else {
            alert(status)
            status = true;
        }

     }, false);
}

f();
```

When using this, always know what you are referring to. As Isac pointed out, your `this` referred to the document window, which seems to have been an issue.

**Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/foozie3moons/pen/gGRBxZ?editors=0010

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="toggle"> toggle </a>'+ document.body.innerHTML;
function f() {
    let status = true;
    let btn = document.getElementById("toggle");
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (status === true) {
            alert(status);
            status = false;
        } else {
            alert(status);
            status = true;
        }

    }, false)
}

f();
```