# AngularJS: Use DTO models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, dto, data-transfer-objects

Is there a way to have a DTO.

So on my back-end part I have a pretty clear domains, e.g. Client.

```
class Client {
    protected $firstName;
    protected $lastName;
}
```

In fact it is a class, that contain specific properties. I want to have something similar on my front-end part. I want to be sure that the object came to a function is an instance of `Client` and I can refer to specific Client properties.

Another question - is it an appropriate approach to organize AngularJS (1.5.9) application?. Would it decrease application performance?

P.S. I want to get something like this on my front-end part

```
function someFunc(client) {
    if (!(client instanceof Client)) {
        // handle error
    }
// here I can refer to client.firstName or client.lastName and not get undefined, as long as it is a required Client properties
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Javascript is an untyped language.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964910/is-javascript-an-untyped-language) Put that simply, you cannot achieve what you want.

A workaround could be to add a method `getType()` in your `Client` class with an `Enum` returned and check that field in Angular.

If you want instead a "typed" version of JS check [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Answer (score 1):

as of ES6 you can use classes and do something like this

```
var Animal = {
  speak() {
    console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
  }
};

class Dog {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

// If you do not do this you will get a TypeError when you invoke speak
Object.setPrototypeOf(Dog.prototype, Animal);

var d = new Dog('Mitzie');
d.speak(); // Mitzie makes a noise.
```

check out MDN docs for further details, 
[MDN - Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes),
[MDN - instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)