# Is the operation between string and number available?

Tags: javascript, react-native

What is the result of '4' / 2 ?

```
"4" / 2 = 2
```

Is it right?

Why this operation is available?

How to can explain this operation?

Comment: `"4" / 2 = 2` is a `SyntaxError`, and `"4" === 4` is `false`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does string to number comparison work in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript)

Comment: In console terminal '4' / 2 is equal to 2 and vscode really!

Answer (score 1):

As per the description in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

=== operator can be used in case of comparing value & type both.

For your case, "4" is a string type & 4 is number. So type of "4" & 4 is not equal.
Hence "4" === 4 will return false.

Where as if you use == operator which doesn't compare type but values only, will return true.
Hence "4" == 4 will return true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is right. `/` operator converts operands to numbers before calculation. i.e. it implicitly reads a number when a string is passed. So its result is always Number whatever operands are.

From the ECMAScript spec:

> [**11.5 Multiplicative Operators**](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5)
>
> (...)
>
> 1. Let left be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
>
> 2. Let leftValue be GetValue(left).
>
> 3. Let right be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
>
> 4. Let rightValue be GetValue(right).
>
> 5. **Let leftNum be ToNumber(leftValue).**
>
> 6. **Let rightNum be ToNumber(rightValue).**
>
> 7. Return the result of applying the specified operation (*, /, or %) to leftNum and rightNum.

As to "why?", because it is a [weakly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690544/what-is-the-difference-between-a-strongly-typed-language-and-a-statically-typed) [typed language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/964910) ([Netscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Beginnings_at_Netscape) developers designed them to be [tolerant about types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)).