# Javascript - charAt is not a function error

Tags: javascript

I made a mistake in the code below. In a variable "x", I stored one character from a string "s". Then, I mistakenly incremented "x" which caused the error given after the code. Why does JS allow me to increment a character variable in the first place ? How do I prevent such errors from happening ?

```
function jsFun(s){
    var x = s.charAt(0);
    s++;//Wrong !
    x = s.charAt(1);
    return x;
}

console.log(jsFun("one"));
```

**Error :** In line 4.

```
TypeError: s.charAt is not a function
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the `s++`? This is causing the error because it only makes sense for numbers (so JS, in its "helpful" way, is coercing `s` to be a number on that line).

Comment: @RobinZigmond - This code is just a snippet from much bigger code in which two variables had similar names - s and sId. I had to increment sId, but I mistakenly incremented s instead. Is there a term for the "coercion" ? I will google that term to learn more.

Comment: Coercion is the general term for when JS automatically converts a variable to a different type.

Comment: @RobinZigmond - I searched coercion javascript. The formal name for this is Type Coercion.

Comment: `s` is not a number type and can't be incremented

Comment: @MisterJojo - Yes, I have clearly mentioned that in my question. I wanted to know the reason why JS allows it.

Comment: **again** in your function `jsFun` `s` is the argument and it is not a number type and can't be incremented

Comment: @masterjoe2 Javascript is a weakly typed language, meaning that many strange operations are "valid" and won't cause errors directly. For example you can sum a string and a number but can't subtract.

Comment: @MisterJojo - Yes. You keep repeating the same thing. The answer I was looking for is "Type Coercion". Please see the comment by Robin Zigmond.

Comment: I perfectly know what is type coercion in javascript, making your incrémentation on `s` is exactly the case

Comment: your `s++` transform the `s` argument in a number (NaN in reality)  ==> this is the type coercion, then the string method `.charAt()` can't be applied to a  number (or a NaN) and make your error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the ECMAScript Language Specification allows it https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.4.

The only time the `++` unary operator would throw a SyntaxError is if all the following are true:

- Type(expr) is Reference is true
- IsStrictReference(expr) is true
- Type(GetBase(expr)) is Environment Record
- GetReferencedName(expr) is either "eval" or "arguments"

Otherwise, it will try to parse the value into a number and increase it by one. A string does not meet the throwing criteria, so it gets parsed to a number (resulting in `NaN` in your example) and then, after increasing its value by 1, it still returns `NaN`.

If the string was numeric such as `"1234"`, you would see that it gets turned into a number and increased by one, as you would expect with a number. Once you try to call the `charAt` function, however, your code would error out, since numbers do not have that function.

To prevent this behaviour using plain Javascript, you could check whether the variable is a non-NaN number before increasing it

```
if (!Number.isNaN(s)) {
   s++
}
```

You could also use `isNaN` if you would like to verify is the string is numeric-ish.

Also, like other answers said, you could use a type-checked alternative such as Typescript or a static type checker such as flow.js to prevent these errors at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

As some have mentioned JavaScript will let you do this because is weakly typed. Here is a good post about it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/964926/8161471

How can you prevent it? There are tools you can use like extensions with your editor that will highlight such problems as you work on your code. TypeScript, a superset of JavaScript, is another good alternative which can give you a more strongly type approach that looks a lot like C#/Java.
[What is TypeScript and why would I use it in place of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript#:~:text=TypeScript%20is%20a%20superset%20of%20the%20JavaScript%20language%20that%20has,make%20JavaScript%20development%20more%20efficient).