# Returning a tuple in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, tuples

I have an array of pokemon objects which have a Max and Min height (see snapshot below) and I need to return the average minimum and maximum height for all pokemon in the form of a tuple

```
const allPokemon = [
  {
    Height: {
      Minimum: '0.61m',
      Maximum: '0.79m',
    },
  },
];
```

I need to use HOFs so I was thinking to do something like this for both Maximum and Minimum height:

```
allPokemon.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + parseInt(cur.Height.Maximum), 0) / allPokemon.length;
allPokemon.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + parseInt(cur.Height.Minimum), 0) / allPokemon.length;
```

but I'm not sure how to return the two values in the form of a tuple (create empty array and push the values in? Concat method?)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `object` would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For now, JavaScript doesn’t have tuples. Besides, [Javascript is weakly typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964910/is-javascript-an-untyped-language)

> Weakly typed means the compiler, if applicable, doesn't enforce
> correct typing. Without implicit compiler interjection, the
> instruction will error during run-time.

However, with the `object` or `array destructuring` you can archive it

1. You can use `.reduce` with initial data as `object` like `{ Maximum: 0, Minimum: 0 }` to aggregate your data like below:

```js
const allPokemon = [
        {
          Height: {
            Minimum: "1.61m",
            Maximum: "2.79m"
           }
        }]
        
var result = allPokemon.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      acc.Maximum += (parseFloat(cur.Height.Maximum)/allPokemon.length);      
      acc.Minimum += (parseFloat(cur.Height.Minimum)/allPokemon.length);
      
      return acc; 
}, { Maximum: 0, Minimum: 0 });

console.log(result);
```

2. The second way is using `array` then [`destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like this

```js
const allPokemon = [
        {
          Height: {
            Minimum: "1.61m",
            Maximum: "2.79m"
           }
        }]
        
var result = allPokemon.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      acc[0] += (parseFloat(cur.Height.Maximum)/allPokemon.length);      
      acc[1] += (parseFloat(cur.Height.Minimum)/allPokemon.length);
      
      return acc; 
}, [0, 0]);

console.log(result);

// Array Destructuring here
const [Maximum, Minimum] = result;
console.log("Maximum: " + Maximum);
console.log("Minimum: " + Minimum);
```

For example:

```
const [a, b] = [10, 20]; // a = 10, b= 20
```

**Note:** As @VLAZ 's comment, in the near future we'd have proper `tuples` and `records` like this one [proposal-record-tuple](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple)

Comment: @Phong Mostly yes thank you! How would I implement the allPokemon.length within the code itself rather than in the console.log?

Comment: It depends on your logic, you can also move `/allPokemon.length` into individual calculating like `acc.Maximum += (parseFloat(cur.Height.Maximum)/allPokemon.length)`. But it should move out to calculate average :) @ruggle

Comment: I need it to return as an array with the two values i.e. [1,61, 2.79]

Comment: Of course, you can use `the second solution` with `destructuring assignment` : @ruggle

Comment: ahh, didn't see that one! Thanks for your help! I wasn't aware of the array destructuring technique. I'll need to read upon it!

Comment: "*No, JavaScript doesn’t have tuples (Because javascript weakly typed)*" being weakly typed doesn't have any bearing on having tuples or not. Weakly typed means that conversions can happen. That doesn't mean types don't exist - there are already numbers and strings, among others. A tuple can just be another type and [indeed there is a proposal for it](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple). Hopefully in the near future we'd have proper tuples and records (basically named tuples).

Answer (score 3):

```js
const allPokemon = [
        {
          Height: {
            Minimum: "1.61m",
            Maximum: "2.79m"
           }
        }]
        
const [avgMin, avgMax] = allPokemon.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      acc[0] += parseFloat(cur.Height.Minimum);      
      acc[1] += parseFloat(cur.Height.Maximum);
      
      return acc; 
}, [0, 0]).map(total => total / allPokemon.length)

console.log(`Average min: ${avgMin}\nAverage max: ${avgMax}`);
```

The first value of the result tuple is the average minimum and the second is the average maximum.

Comment: Your updated answer is using `destructuring array` like me ^^!

Answer (score 1):

There's no tuple in JavaScript, you may return an array instead. JS will unpack into variables.

```js
function foo(){
    return ["value1","value2"];
}

[var1,var2] = foo();
console.log(var1,var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need hof (look at others answers) however if you *really* want to use hof (e.g as an exercise)
you need a function which takes a function as parameter

So e.g

take a function which extracts the numerical property
and take a function which uses it to average the data.

```
function getValue(pokemon) {
  return pokemon.height.Maximum
}

function avgBy(getValue, pokemons) {
  return pokemons.length === 0 ? 0 : pokemons.reduce((s, p) => s + getValue(p), 0) / pokemons.length
}
```

Then you can indeed compose:

```
function getMin (pokemon) { return pokemon.height.Minimum }
function getMax (pokemon) { return pokemon.height.Maximum }
const [min, max] = [avgBy(getMin, pokemons), avgBy(getMax, pokemons)]
```

The nice property is now you have the avgBy which can compute the avg of whatever as long you give it a proper `getValue` func

```js
function getMin (pokemon) { return pokemon.height.Minimum }
function getMax (pokemon) { return pokemon.height.Maximum }

function avgBy(getValue, pokemons) {
  return pokemons.length === 0 ? 0 : pokemons.reduce((s, p) => s + getValue(p), 0) / pokemons.length
}
const pokemons = [{height:{Maximum: 1, Minimum: 0}}, {height:{Maximum: 3, Minimum:1}}]
const [min, max] = [avgBy(getMin, pokemons), avgBy(getMax, pokemons)]
console.log({min, max})
```